# Does using move cstor lose memory when the source obj is destroyed?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, move-semantics, move-constructor

Say I have a class

```
MyClass {
  //.. cstors and dstor
  void MyClass(MyClass&& source) : some_obj_(std::move(source.some_obj_));
  SomeObj some_obj_;
}
```

Say I do the following:

```
// a1 is defined somewhere else with a wider scope
MyClass a1; 
...
// a2 is defined locally and will go out of scope soon
MyClass a2; 
... //Populate a2's some_obj_ field with data
a1 = std::move(a2); // move instead of copy
```

In this case, the move constructor will be invoked. From what I understand, the move constructor swaps the field pointers between the two so that no copy happens.

So here comes my question. When `a2` is instantiated, it allocates memory within `a2` itself for field `some_obj_`. When the move happens, we swap the pointers so that now `a1`'s `some_obj_` points to the chunk of memory that `a2` holds (instead of copying it over its own memory space). In the future, when `a2` goes out of scope, e.g. function containing `a2` returns so the stack frame is cleaned up, since `a2.some_obj_` resides within `a2`, it also gets deleted. Since `a1.some_obj_`, after the move, points to `a2`'s memory that has been cleaned now, does `a1` lose that part of the information?

It seems that following the above logic, `a1` will now pointing to invalid memory space.

Comment: What you are describing would happen if you implement or use a buggy move constructor. And there's not enough information in your post to determine whether that is the case.

Comment: How about this update?

Comment: The code for the move assign constructor seems to be missing.

Comment: We have no idea what `SomeObj` does. We don't even know what "field pointers" you're talking about.

Comment: You say, "we swap the pointers", but your example contains no pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a typical implementation of a moving class

```
template<typename T>
struct moving
{
  moving()=default;
  explicit moving(size_t n)
  : ptr(new T[n]) {}
  moving(moving const&)=delete;
  moving&operator=(moving const&)=delete;
  moving(moving&&m)
  : ptr(m.ptr) { m.ptr=nullptr; }
  moving&operator=(moving&&m)
  { if(this!=&m) { delete ptr; ptr=m.ptr; m.ptr=nullptr; } return*this; }
private:
  T*ptr=nullptr;
};
```

So you can figure out by yourself what will happen.

Note that move semantics are only relevant to situations where external resources are managed (such as pointers holding the address of allocated memory or handles to some type of library-managed resources like HDF5 ids). For other ordinary data, moving is no different from copying.

Answer (score 1):

If the move constructor is properly implemented, you don't leak any memory. In particular, a typical move constructor sets the rhs pointer to `nullptr`, so a subsequent `delete` in the destructor of the moved-from object is a no-op. Super simplified example:

```
X::X(X&& rhs)
{
    this->p = rhs.p; // here p is a pointer
    rhs.p = nullptr; // now the delete p from the dtor of rhs is a no-op
}
```

Comment: So in this case, it actually COPIES `p` from `rhs`? I thought it was pointer swapping so that `this->p` now points to `rhs`'s `p`'s memory location and vice versa.

Comment: You copy the pointer `p`, not the data it points to. So effectively it is a swap of the data.

Comment: What if the field is some object, instead of pointers? Move cstor actually copies the objects instead of swapping them (e.g. changing `&(this-obj)` so that it points to `rhs.obj`)?

Comment: This was a simplified example. In case you have more complicated member objects, then it better be the case that all of them defined a move constructor. Then the default move constructor of the composite object will invoke each component move constructor, so you don't even bother writing a move constructor. Example: `struct X{std::string member;}`. The default move constructor of `X` "knows" how to move, since `std::string` implements a move ctor.

Comment: But when it recursively goes down to the deepest move cstor you will call, it would indeed copy the value? Is this what you are saying?

Comment: @OneZero I will do whatever you tell it to do. If you deal with raw pointers, then yes, a move constructor typically copies the pointer, **not the data it points to**.